# Vimeo video autoplay is not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, vimeo

I have a landing page where I added a background video. This video is hosted on **vimeo** platform.

Video autoplay is completely working on all devices **except iPhone mobile**. So please suggest me the solution to autoplay background video on iPhone mobile.

Please check following iFrame code -

`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/479105292?autoplay=1&background=1&hd=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&muted=1&playsinline=1" frameborder="0" data-fullscreeneo="" frameborder="0"allow="autoplay; fullscreen" fullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: The attributes are all fine, it should work. Please set a whitespace between frameborder="0"allow="autoplay; Maybe this cause a synthax error.

Comment: I put your iFrame into CodeSandbox online and tested on my iOS mobile (iOS 14.2) in Safari and Chrome. Both started autoplay imediately without issues: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-vimeo-frwf7